# providing user authentication using bash script

Tags: bash, logging

Actually  very new user to bash.and I am logging into server using

```
ssh sam@xyz.com
```

and now I have to write script which will ensure that only 'sam' user can be logged in.

Can anybody help me out of this problem?

Comment: You mean only sam can log in using that script, or only sam can be logged into the system atall?

Comment: @jarek : Only Sam can be logged into the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly and where you're trying to do, but maybe you're talking about

```
[[ "$(id -un)" = "sam" ]] || { echo "Oh NO! You're a stranger!" ; exit 1; }
```

But generally, `ssh` has its own means of authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to allow the user "sam" into the system via ssh the best way to go is by editing the `/etc/sshd_config` file and restricting access to users at the ssh level.

Towards the end of the file you will see the directive `AllowUsers`. Uncomment this and add the users that are allowed to ssh in so in your case:

```
AllowUsers sam
```

It is a good security practice to limit who can ssh into your box, also don't allow root logins via ssh.

You can find more information [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-deny-or-restrict-access-to-users-and-groups.html).